# Hadoop Task Scheduling

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I am a little bit confused regarding task assignment in Hadoop, I already know how task scheduling such as FIFO, Fair and capacity schedulers for multiple jobs work. But my question is how one scheduler, lets say FIFO, manages the assignment of map tasks for one job with multiple inputs? 
In other words, how FIFO determine the order of execution for the map tasks of the multiple inputs job?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [FAQ on how to question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) Add more details on what you found on documentation. Current version seems too broad

Comment: FIFO doesn't apply internally to map reduce task order, only applications. Maps need to read blocks from files. If you have multiple inputs that aren't dependent on each other, order doesn't matter, and both inputs read at once